# From for loop on dict to multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, python-multithreading, dask

I have a dictionary of 4 `pandas.DataFrame` where I loop over to finally produce ML model.
It would be more efficient to parallelize the process and produce the 4 models at the same time.

What's the best approach, using `multiprocessing` or some Dask feature (like multi pd.DataFrame with a dask.DataFrame) ?

```
for key, df in ready_df_dict.items():
    produce_ml_model(df)
```

EDIT : I can change the input format from a dict to something else if it's smarter.

Answer (score 1):

See the introductory example for custom workloads at https://examples.dask.org/delayed.html for probably the simplest answer. The solution may look like:

```
from dask import delayed, compute

out = [delayed(produce_ml_model)(df)
       for df in ready_df_dict.values()]

compute(out)
```

Note that in the call to `compute` you can choose which scheduler to use.